# Adding an help window to my android application

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

i need to add an help window to my android application. 
But actually i don't know how to do it if there is a best practice, or some prepare objects.

I simply want to add an help option in the application menu, and when it is chooesed the help is showed. What is the best way to do that?

I think about several solution, but i'm not sure they are good.

1. Add another activity that contains only a text view or a webview and print the contente of the help
2. Use a Dialog Box? Maybe a custom dialog?
3. Launch a web activity and retrieve the help page from the web.

They are good ideas? Btw what is the best way to provide a basic help page into an android application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is suitable if your amount of help is **small** and does **not need formatting**
2. Is good for **formatted text**, bigger amounts of text and does **not require internet connection** or your server to be present when user likes to have help
3. Is the **most flexible**, as you can change  help information without updating application,
   but requires **dedicated web page** and **internet connection**.

Now it's your choice. My personal preference is #2.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make a xml layout containing all the help information and just create an activity that displays it, if you need help with code just ask me.